# How to compare a column of a csv file with an image name in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file that lists image files with an ID number for each, like this:

```
21_cook.png   9
35_read.png   6
13_walk.png   2
```

The image files are in a folder.
The code below searches out the image file names:

```
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./images'):
   for filename in filenames:
       if filename.endswith('.png'):
           names.append(filename)
```

This part works.

This code extracts the image names from the CSV file:

```
file = open('namesIma.csv')
lns = csv.reader(file)
for line in lns:
    nam = line [0]
    names1.append(nam)
```

How can I print the ID number of each file that's in both the **images** folder and the CSV file's index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a clause to your **for** loop over the names:

```
for line in lns:
    nam = line [0]
    names1.append(nam)
    if nam in names:
        print (nam, line[1])
```

Does that solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

**if nam in names:
        print (nam, line[1])**

does not return anything
also when I check:

1. type(nam) it gives str
2. type(names)  it give list