# How to match the .mp4 files present in a folder with the names in .csv file and sort according to some column value, in python?

Tags: python, csv, compare

I have a folder containing about 500 .mp4 files :

```
abc.mp4 
lmn.mp4 
ijk.mp4
```

Also I have a .csv file containing the file names (>500) and some values associated with them:

```
file name  value
abc.mp4  5
xyz.mp4  3
lmn.mp4  5
rgb.mp4  4
```

I want to match the file names of .csv and folder and then place the mp4 files in separate folders depending on the value.

```
**folder 5:** 
abc.mp4
lmn.mp4

**folder 3:**
xyz.mp4 
and so on
```

I tried  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557603/how-to-compare-a-column-of-a-csv-file-with-an-image-name-in-python)

```
names=[]
names1=[]

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./videos_test'):
  for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith('.mp4'):
       names.append(filename)


file = open('names.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
lns = csv.reader(file)
for line in lns:
  nam = line [0]
  sc=line[1]
  names1.append(nam)

  if nam in names:
      print (nam, line[1])
      if line[1]==5
        print ('5')
        print(nam) %just prints the name of file not save
      else if line[1]==3
        print ('3')
        print(nam)
```

does not give any result.

Comment: Paste the code you wrote for this, else it is difficult to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use `pandas` if you're going to handle `csv` files.

Here's a code that will automatically create the folders, and put the files in the right place for you using `shutil` and `pandas`. I have assumed that your csv's columns are "filename" and "value". Change them if there's a mismatch.

```
import pandas as pd 
import shutil 
import os

path_to_csv_file = "file.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv_file)

mp4_root = "mp4_root"

destination_path = "destination_path"

#In order to remove the folder if previously created. You can delete this if you don't like it.
if os.path.isdir(destination_path):
    shutil.rmtree(destination_path)
os.mkdir(destination_path)

unique_values = pd.unique(df['value'])

for u in unique_values:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(destination_path, str(u)))

#Here we iterate over the rows of your csv file, and concatenate the value and the filename to the destination_path with our new folder structure.

for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cur_path = os.path.join(destination_path, str(row['value']), str(row['filename']))
        source_path = os.path.join(mp4_root, str(row['filename']))
        shutil.copyfile(source_path, cur_path)
```

**EDIT**: If there's a file that is in the csv but not present in the source folder, you could check it before (more pythonic) or you could handle it via a try/catch exception check.(Not recommended)

Check the code below.

```
source_files = os.listdir(mp4_root)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if str(row['filename']) not in source_files:
            continue
        cur_path = os.path.join(destination_path, str(row['value']), str(row['filename']))
        source_path = os.path.join(mp4_root, str(row['filename']))
        shutil.copyfile(source_path, cur_path)
```

Comment: In case the file is not present in  folder but is present in the .csv list, or vice versa how to handle it.

Comment: Also add one more ')' at the end of str(row['value']) i.e  cur_path = os.path.join(destination_path, str(row['value']), str(row['filename'])))

Comment: The 'if condition'  doesnt seem to work!! I think there is some problem with the data type of source_file (list) and row['filename'] (string).

Comment: @mumtaz well the if condition checks whether the filename is in the list or not. you could individually match those but this is a more pythonic way of checking if an item is in a list or not. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-check-if-element-exists-in-list/

Comment: This helped.. Thanks .............https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-test-if-string-contains-element-from-list/